Blender 4.2 developer extras not appearing in panel options
I have enabled Developer extras in 4.2 but these options are not appearing.

in 3.4, I have them available:


it's in the dropdown menu (Mesh Edit Mode) right next to the overlay menu on the right side.

Thanks for pointing it out, they split it up in the new version, it was more convenient in one panel, in my opinion, Nevertheless, thank you!

It might have been more convenient, but it actually makes sense in my opinion (especially to new users which are probably not familiar with the old version) to have one menu that deals with settings of the overlays in Object Mode and another one for the overlays in Edit Mode. Of course context menus for example are simply switching to different settings between modes, but here you need both - because even if you are in Edit Mode, you can still affect the Object Mode settings since some of them are valid in both modes and if not they are still used on the other objects not being edited.

And so with the necessity to have both at the same time and not just exchanging one menu for the other depending on Object Mode or Edit Mode, the old menu was very long in_Edit Mode_ in my opinion, with all the features specifically used for editing all down at the bottom. Another option would have been to move the Edit Mode specific settings at the top, but this could cause confusion because someone might be confused what happened to the settings which are usually at the top in Object Mode. So once I knew they had changede the UI this was an improvement from my point of view...

I see your point of view, very much respected. But because I switched from 3.4 to 4.2 I was use to the way it was. But with time Ill get use to the new layout. Cheers.
